# Query JSON files stored in S3 buckets with Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I would like to create sql queries against some files stored in S3, using Athena. However I'm having some difficulties due to the structure of the files. The structure of the file is always the same, however the indentation might be different for each file. Some example listed below.

There are a tons of files formatted like this and I need to do basic SQL queries on them. I only have read-access to the s3 buckets and would like to avoid duplicating the whole buckets just to change indentation to make it work with athena.

Do you have any idea how these might be achieved?

I tried importing the table either straight via Athena and via Glue but it doesn't work. While creating it via Athena I get this error `Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}' at 48 [character 49 line 1]` which should be caused by the fact that the files starts with an array.

Example file 1:

```
[{"name":"sample name1", "category":"category 1"},{"name":"sample name2", "category":"category 2"}]
```

Example file 2:

```
[{"name":"sample name3", "category":"category 1"},
{"name":"sample name4", "category":"category 3"}]
```

Example file 3:

```
[
    {"name":"sample name1", "category":"category 1"},
    {"name":"sample name5", "category":"category 3"}
]
```

Comment: Basically I think would need something to preprocess the json files to output them in the desired format of Athena. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If I create a glue crawler using `$[*]` as classifier and I try to use it in Athena when I select "Preview Table" I get the error `Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Missing value at 1 [character 2 line 1]`